# Multi dimensional symbolic dynamics

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, symbolic-dynamics

I want to learn Multi dimensional symbolic dynamics. can you point to any recent thesis containing a good exposition or lecture notes?

Comment: I don't know a lot about the ergodic theory of $\mathbb{Z}^d$-actions, but Ronnie Pavlov's 2007 thesis has a section on multidimensional shifts of finite type which might perhaps be useful: http://web.cs.du.edu/~rpavlov/RPdissertation.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Klaus Schmidt and I wrote a survey about multi-dimensional dynamics in 2002, which you can find at:  *Symbolic and algebraic dynamical systems*, Handbook of dynamical systems, Vol. 1A, 765–812, North-Holland, Amsterdam, 2002. A lot has happened since, but it would be a good starting point.